# PHP PDO Update multiple rows I just can't work it out

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, pdo

Hi guys I am trying to update my database via PHP using the PDO method, my script connects to my database and selects all the data required depending on the set clientID, it then works out the difference between today's date and the created date.

It then goes on to assign each result a weight based on age (a number between 1 and 6)

What I need it to do is update all records in the database where the clientID is the same, with the new weight.

> this is where I go wrong ALL WORK's FINE UP UNTIL THIS POINT! my UPDATE statement only updates the last (highest) ID (if more than one record comes back with the same clientID)

```
$hostdb = '';
$namedb = '';
$userdb = '';
$passdb = '';
try{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb; dbname=$namedb", $userdb, $passdb);
    $conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");      // Sets encoding UTF-8
    $sql = "UPDATE parked SET weight = :weight  
            WHERE ID = :ID";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);                                  
$stmt->bindParam(':ID', $ID, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$stmt->bindParam(':weight', $weight, PDO::PARAM_INT);  


$stmt->execute(); 
$conn = null;        // Disconnect
}

catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

As I have never updated more than one record at a time before and usually by $_POST not inside the script itself I am really struggling.

DB IMAGE

[image: Database]

[image: Database]

Things to NOTE:
I am getting no err messages!

Comment: This is a lot of code and a lot of detail, most of it unnecessary. You will get much better help if you boil this down somewhat to a simple example. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also, if you're wanting to update multiple rows with different values in a single statement, you are looking for the `CASE ... WHEN ...` syntax.

Comment: For easy debug since your problem is not updating , try to echo your update statement and run it on your SQL

Comment: @mike1992 There's an [edit] link right under the question.

Comment: Also to avoid SQL Injection use prepared statements for this: $sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM parked WHERE clientID = $clientID");

Comment: echo $ID. Is this the id you want?

Comment: yes, the database image cuts of the weight field sorry (it is there) :)

Comment: In which table is weight column?

Comment: as mentioned above your comment the image in my description has cut off the weight column but it is there

Comment: Your DSN should **not** have spaces in it. You should set the connection charset there too, ie `new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb;dbname=$namedb;charset=utf8", $userdb, $passdb);` instead of using the `SET...` query

Comment: Thanks for that I will update, However does anyone have an answer to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your update query only updates one record because you pass only one record, the very last one in the previous select statement. To pass multiple records, you would need to create a `$weight[]` array, calculate each row of select statement, push value into array, and then loop each item iteratively through the update query.

However, all you do in PHP can be done in a MySQL Update SQL query as MySQL carries the [DateDiff()](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/datediff.php) and Now() functions, and nested logical `CASE/WHEN` statement (in fact, even `IF/THEN`). Hence, you only need to connect once to run the action query:

```
try{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb; dbname=$namedb", $userdb, $passdb);
    $conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");      // Sets encoding UTF-8
    $sql = "UPDATE parked 
            SET weight =
              CASE 
                WHEN DATEDIFF(NOW(), datecreated) <= 21 THEN 1 
                WHEN DATEDIFF(NOW(), datecreated) >= 22 AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), datecreated) < 42 THEN 2 
                WHEN DATEDIFF(NOW(), datecreated) >= 43 AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), datecreated) < 63 THEN 3 
                WHEN DATEDIFF(NOW(), datecreated) >= 63 AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), datecreated) < 84 THEN 4 
                WHEN DATEDIFF(NOW(), datecreated) >= 84 AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), datecreated) < 105 THEN 5 
                WHEN DATEDIFF(NOW(), datecreated) >= 105 THEN 6 
              END;";
    $stmt = $conn->execute($sql);                                         
    $conn = null;  
}

 catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```